# Integral $\int_{-1}^{K} x^{B+1} e^{-Nx} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, approximate-integration

What is the solution of the following integral:

$$
\int_{-1}^{K} x^{B+1} e^{-Nx} dx
$$

where $N$ and $B$ are constants

Comment: I tried using the exponential formula for integration, Gamma Function and integration by parts. The problem is that i have about 7-8 terms involving this kind of expression and i needs a simplified form of the above integral.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? Analytical expression? Numerical approximation? Existence criterion in terms of those constants?

Comment: Yes, i need an analytical expression of the expression.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives an analytical expression for $\int x^{b+1} e^{-nx} dx$ in terms of the incomplete Gamma function or the generalized exponential integral.

Comment: Please let me know the answer.

Comment: Huh? Just enter `integral x^(b+1)exp(-nx)`!